# Illustrator: how to remove a path that I typed on

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustrator, I was following a youtube video on how to type on a path. When I type on my path the path line itself remains.

I need to remove the line that I pointed to in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Select it with whie arriw tool and set steoke to none?

Answer (score 1):

Use the direct selection tool (shortcut is A) and set stroke to none.

Comment: this didn't work . can u show me by screenshot ?